# why the list is not printed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I'm trying to make a code that put all the friends(the people he follows) of a user in a list and then prints it.. but for some reason its not working. there is no error but list is not printed.

```
import tweepy
from api_keys import *


auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
   consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)





li = []
for friend in(tweepy.Cursor(api.get_friends,screen_name="elonmusk").items()):   

   li.append(friend.screen_name)


print (li)
```

Comment: Maybe the output of the tweepy.Cursor call is empty

Comment: there is a space after `print`

Comment: how did you install `api_keys` ?

Comment: the api_keys are imported from another file... and it works fine with other code i use tweepy

Comment: Did you try with another account than the one of Elon Musk?